# How to install / set up UIMA DUCC on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: uima, ducc

I'm totally new to UIMA DUCC. I'm trying to install/set up UIMA DUCC for the first time (on Ubuntu 16.04) and am facing issues executing commands given @ https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/UIMA/DUCC#DUCC-t0
as it is Redhat specific.

The following exception occurs while executing **./start_ducc**;

**Exception**

```
ducc@s4cchinpc408:~/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/admin$ ./start_ducc 
Merging /home/ducc/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/resources/default.ducc.properties with /home/ducc/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/resources/site.ducc.properties into /home/ducc/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/resources/ducc.properties
Set ducc_ling version from s4cchinpc408 : /home/ducc/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/admin/amd64/ducc_ling -v >/home/ducc/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/state/duccling.version
JVM: /usr/bin/java
ENV: Java is configured as: /usr/bin/java
ENV java full version "1.7.0_80-b15"
ENV: Threading enabled: True
MEM: memory is 7 gB
ENV: system is Linux
allnodes /home/ducc/apache-uima-ducc-2.0.0/resources/ducc.nodes
Class definition file is ducc.classes
java.net.UnknownHostException: s4cchinpc408: s4cchinpc408: Temporary failure in name resolution
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
at org.apache.uima.ducc.common.NodeConfiguration.getDomainName(NodeConfiguration.java:215)
at org.apache.uima.ducc.common.NodeConfiguration.readConfiguration(NodeConfiguration.java:990)
at org.apache.uima.ducc.common.NodeConfiguration.main(NodeConfiguration.java:1286)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: s4cchinpc408: Temporary failure in name resolution
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
... 3 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.ducc.common.NodeConfiguration.getDomainName(NodeConfiguration.java:220)
at org.apache.uima.ducc.common.NodeConfiguration.readConfiguration(NodeConfiguration.java:990)
at org.apache.uima.ducc.common.NodeConfiguration.main(NodeConfiguration.java:1286)
NOTOK: Cannot validate class and/or node definitions.
NOTOK: Bad configuration, cannot start.
```

**NOTE:**

**Start sshd** - could not be done on Ubuntu. Instead I just installed ssh using **apt-get install ssh**

```
[degenaro@oc4534203605 ~]$ sudo su root
[sudo] password for degenaro:
[root@oc4534203605 degenaro]# chkconfig sshd on
[root@oc4534203605 degenaro]# /sbin/service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [FAILED]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[root@oc4534203605 degenaro]# exit
exit
[degenaro@oc4534203605 ~]$
```

**FYR:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277464/what-is-the-equivalent-command-for-chkconfig-sshd-on-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment67815058_40277464

Comment: I think the NPE is coming from InetAddress.getLocalHost() returning null. What do the "hostname" and "hostname -f" commands return?

Comment: Did you confirm password-less ssh to the machine from itself is working? Was ducc_post_install run with no errors?

Comment: Ya, ducc_post_install ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

Running DUCC on ubuntu 16.04 worked for me.

1. adduser ducc
2. download ducc 2.1.0 .gz
3. umask 022 + untar + ducc_post_install
4. install ssh (was not already installed)

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-linux

5. enable passwordless ssh

https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

6. start_ducc

=====

Why are you getting UnknownHostException?  Here's a small java program you can try without any DUCC involvement:

**TestMe.java**

```
package test;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TestMe {

    private static String getDomainName()
    {
        InetAddress me = null;
        try {
            me = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String my_happy_name = me.getHostName();
            String my_canonical_name = me.getCanonicalHostName();
            if ( my_canonical_name.startsWith(my_happy_name) ) {
                int ndx = my_canonical_name.indexOf(".");
                return my_canonical_name.substring(ndx+1);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDomainName());
    }
}
```

Lou.